# Increasing scroll height when a tooltip appear

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tooltip, react-bootstrap

I have a table and when hover on certain data of a table column i'm displaying a tool tip. Following image shows it. The issue is when hovering the bottom records, the height of the table won't increase to make room to the tool tip.

The following image shows when hovering data of the top of part of the table. There is no issue with this.

[image]

But when hovering bottom part of the table , the position of the tool tip will become incorrect as shown in the following figure (Here i have hovered the last record of the table)

[image]

I tried giving much higher hight for the table manually. Then i can get the expected behaviour

[image]

I do not want to give the table height manually , i want it to increase height automatically. How can i achieve this target

Table code is as follows

```
<Table responsive striped borderless hover>
       <thead>
          <tr id="table_col_names">
             <th className="label_type2 pl-lg-5 pl-xs-2 pb-4">Allowed Stations</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          {consumers.consumerData && consumers.consumerData.map((item, key) => {
          return (
          <tr key={key}>
             <td className="cell_style pl-lg-5 pl-xs-2">
                <OverlayTrigger
                placement='bottom'
                overlay={
                <Tooltip bsPrefix="consumer_tooltip">
                   {Object.values(this.groupData(item.allowedChargingStations)).map((evc,key) => {
                   return (
                   <div>
                      <p>{evc.groupName}</p>
                      {evc.stations.map((evcStation, key) => {
                      return (
                      <p className="ml-3">
                      <li>{evcStation.name}</li>
                      </p>
                      )
                      })}
                   </div>
                   )
                   })}
                </Tooltip>
                }
                >
                <label className="cp">{item.allowedChargingStations.length} stations</label>
                </OverlayTrigger>
             </td>
          </tr>
          )
          })}
       </tbody>
    </Table>
```

i have used react bootstrap component `OverlayTrigger` and `Tooltip` for the tool tip.

**tool tip css**

```
.consumer_tooltip{
    background: rgba(24, 68, 119, 0.5);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10.8731px);
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 160px;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    padding-top: 20px !important;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-left: 64px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    pointer-events: none; 
}
.consumer_tooltip:before{
    content: ' ';
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    left: 18px;
    top:-20px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(24, 68, 119, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Try to use `position:fixed;` with `top:auto`on tooltip

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Are you rendering Tooltip inside <td> or <table> ?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD where did you apply that on `.consumer_tooltip:before` or `.consumer_tooltip`

Comment: @PrashantSharma inside <td>

Comment: @i tried adding to both

Comment: Ideally, we should add Tooltip to the body with absolute position and place it according to event target, that will eliminate the scenario you are facing.